# MainWindow.CreateFile always returns -1

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to eject a USB drive in C# after I've copied some files to it.

However, after reading a lot of the examples of how to do that, I can't get anything to work for me.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLastError();

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile
    (string filename, uint desiredAccess,
        uint shareMode, IntPtr securityAttributes,
        int creationDisposition, int flagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr templateFile);
```

#### How I'm calling it:

```
string path = "\\\\.\\" + driveLetter + ":";

IntPtr handle = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 
  IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

MessageBox.Show(GetLastError().ToString());//gives me zero
```

My drive letter is `K` so it just puts that in the string and attempts to open the file (I'm not really sure about that), I'm hoping it will be the drive so that I can eject the USB thumbdrive.

**Problem is that `handle` is always `-1`**

Am I formatting the `path` string wrong? Or am I using the `CreateFile` method incorrectly to get a handle to the drive I want to eject?

related:

[Eject USB device via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704599/eject-usb-device-via-c-sharp)

[Safely remove a USB drive using the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85649/safely-remove-a-usb-drive-using-the-win32-api) (and related links)

Comment: `GetLastError()` is your friend.  p/invoke knows about it, if you set the right attribute.  Almost certainly though, you have access denied, because you're asking for overwrite access to a disk that's in use by a mounted filesystem.

Comment: it is just returning `0`, but perhaps I'm not using `GetLastError()` correctly?

Comment: You are not, it must be Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().  But don't do that either, exceptions are your friend, very much so in a case like this.  Throw System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception instead and it takes care of everything.  Writing to a disk drive directly does require [super powers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034) given the amount of damage you can do.

Comment: You'll want to use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`.

Comment: let me try that @LeandroTaset  because the files are writing fine, but I'm just trying to eject the drive afterwards.

Comment: still return `-1` for the `handle`, and `GetLastError()` is still `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here (Eject USB device via C#, see Roger Deep's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36226588/420006)

## Short answer:

```
IntPtr handle = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 0x3, 0, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

I have no idea what the difference is, but it gives me the correct handle to the drive and the rest of the code now works!

## Long answer, my complete code to remove a USB drive (WPF Window):

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EjectDrive('K');
}
void EjectDrive(char driveLetter)
{
    string path = @"\\.\" + driveLetter + @":";
    IntPtr handle = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 0x3, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    if ((long)handle == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to open drive " + driveLetter);
        return;
    }

    int dummy = 0;

    DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref dummy, IntPtr.Zero);

    CloseHandle(handle);

    MessageBox.Show("OK to remove drive.");
}
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile
    (string filename, uint desiredAccess,
        uint shareMode, IntPtr securityAttributes,
        int creationDisposition, int flagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr templateFile);
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int DeviceIoControl
    (IntPtr deviceHandle, uint ioControlCode,
        IntPtr inBuffer, int inBufferSize,
        IntPtr outBuffer, int outBufferSize,
        ref int bytesReturned, IntPtr overlapped);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
```